# array as instance variable passed as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, parameter-passing

I have a class with an array as an instance variable/field, which is passed through from another class to the first method in this one.
I was under the impression that I should also be able to access it from another method without also passing it to that method but when I try, I get an NPE.

Here's the code:

```
public class PLoop {

    // instance variable
    public Memory[] memList;

    // method 1
    public void memPass(Memory[] memLocList) {

        memList = memLocList;
        System.out.println(memList.length);
    }

    // method 2
    public void accessArray() {

        System.out.println(memList.length);
    }
}
```

When the first method is called I get an integer printed to the console representing the length of the array but when the second method is called it's NPE, suggesting not the same array.

The second method is called by clicking a button on a GUI. The method associated with this button only has a call along the lines of:

```
PLoop.accessArray();
```

Can anyone tell from this what I'm doing wrong?

-EDIT-
The calls to these methods come from two different classes, each of which declares an instance of PLoop:

```
proc = new PLoop();
```

Comment: Are you calling `accessArray` before `memPass`? (Or on a different object?)

Comment: You've simplified this to the point where the code won't show the problem. As long as you call both methods on the same object, this code will work perfectly. If you call them on different objects, well, then that' another story.

Comment: memPass is called first, then I click a button on the GUI to call accessArray.

Comment: how come this method be called statically??

Comment: Are you sure it's the *same object*?

Comment: Can we see the code you use to call each method?

Comment: PLoop.accessArray(); is thats the way your are calling that method?? calling non-static method using Class name?? that gonna be a compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Methods in your PLoop classes are not static
Still you are calling `PLoop.accessArray();`

Can u please tell what is the real Scenario?

Just like @Jon Skeet told the code seems to be fine.The only possibility is that you may be
executing them out of sequence or you may be messing up with memLocList after the first
method is called.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually written as "proc = new PLoop;" in the main constructor of the gui, then "proc.accessArray();" in the method that calls it.

Comment: are you calling the method2 just after calling method1?

Comment: Yes. Method 2 is called by clicking a button on the GUI after method 1 has already printed out to the console.

Comment: Hey Robert...The issue is fixed right?
It is because the 2 objects are different...
you are setting memList on one Object and calling accessArray on different
object.

Comment: That appears to be the issue but I've yet to track down why it's happening.

Comment: I ended up moving both methods into the same class as the array and it suddenly worked. Still not sure what was going on but, at this stage, I'm happy just to get it to work. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that the instance you've called `memPass` on isn't the same instance you're later calling `accessArray` on.

It should be absolutely fine if you're using the same instance. (In particular, it's the *value* of the argument which will be stored, so it's not like `memList` can become null after not being null, just due to changes elsewhere.)

Answer (score 3):

The code in the class you have shown looks fine, so if you are getting a NPEx then either the methods are being called out of sequence, or the second method call is being made on a different instance of PLoop to the first.

To check if the calls are being made on the same object or not, try printing out the value of `this` inside your methods and check if the values are the same:

```
System.out.println(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip - I am indeed getting different values:
PLoop@79024994 - 1st method and PLoop@78cade31 for the 2nd.